# Heuristic sorting on text match

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk, one-liner

I'd like to order results counting a goodness of match to multiple concurrent text matches.
I want to count partial matches to text searches a collection of searches, e.g. specific characters, bigrams, prefixes.

I want to use bash, awk, command line tools, or one-liners, without writing another script.

For example, say I want to sort by the count of [5 most common english bigrams](https://gist.github.com/lydell/c439049abac2c9226e53) [`th`,`he`,`in`,`er`,`an`] included in the word:

With example wordlist

```
abashed
abashedly
abashedness
abhenry
abolisher
not
```

(from `grep he /usr/share/dict/words | head -n5`, with non-match added).

I want output

```
2 abolisher
1 abhenry
1 abashedness
1 abashedly
1 abashed
0 not
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify and focus on my real issue.

Comment: Your sample input/output doesn't include any cases where the bigrams overlap (e.g. `the` has `th` and `he`) so it's not useful in demonstrating your requirements for that case. Please add a case like that so we can see how it should be handled (1st bigram counted, both counted, or last counted).

Answer (score 2):

For the particular question "sort by the number of vowels", GNU awk is a fine choice:

```sh
produce_words |
gawk '
  {
    vowels = gensub(/[^aeiouy]/, "", "g", tolower($0))
    count[$0] = length(vowels)
  }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (word in count) print count[word], word
  }
'
```

See [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) for the PROCINFO magic.

Answer (score -2):

Awk can do.

Count the number of lines that match some patterns, possibly multiple. Because multiple patterns can match, we can't use regex alternative matches (`/in|er/`) in the solution.

You could write this in one line, though it's awfully repetitive.

```
<10-words.txt tr A-Z a-z 
| awk '//{tot[$0]=0}
    /th/{tot[$0]++}
    /he/{tot[$0]++}
    /in/{tot[$0]++} 
    /er/{tot[$0]++}
    /an/{tot[$0]++}
  END{for (i in tot) print tot[i],i }'
| sort -rn`
```